# Is there a efficient way to find only the combinations of interest from V exciting in P

Tags: python, math, tree, combinations, permutation

Is there a efficient way to find only the combinations of interest from V exciting in P

I have a list of something like this.

```
V = [2,3,5,7,9,12]
```

Size of V can be anywhere from 0 to 50  based on my input.
V has no duplicates.

I have another list P something like this

```
P = [ [1],[1,2],[2,3] [3,4], [3,5,7], [3,5,8] ...]
```

P is constant with size 1000.

P has no duplicates and within P, each element is sorted in ascending order.

What would be an efficient way to find the combinations from V existing in P.

For example

When `V = [2,3,5,7,9,12]` combination of interest would be `[[2,3],[3,5,7]]`.

I have already tried generating all possible arrangements from V and then filter by P.  This is not very efficient. Just wondering if there is a better way to do what I asked for.

Since I already know P is any form of Tree a better option for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Using `set.issuperset` is probably the fastest method in practice:

```
v = set(V)
[c for c in P if v.issuperset(c)]
```

It is also possible to use two pointers, gradually advancing along each list. It will probably be slower in Python, but faster in C/C++:

```
def is_subset(V, combination):
    # both V and combination are assumed sorted
    v = iter(V)
    for element in combination:
        for el in v:
            if el >= element:
                break
        if el != element:
            return False
    return True

[c for c in P if is_subset(V, c)]
```

Comment: `filter(set(V).issuperset, P)`?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, that's more pythonic

Comment: Heh, not sure about that (I do prefer it, but I think many don't). But I believe it's faster.